# Communication service chat - Refresh token not work

Tags: azure, chat, refresh-token, azure-communication-services

I have downloaded azure communication chat service and make to work as shown in the video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2pyKhoIZhJo .

but their is problem.. how i overcome with token expire.. it keep on expiring the treadID, and i cant chat further..

I have mentioned RefreshToken, though its not refreshing. below is the code what I did the changes,

```
 var userCredential = new CommunicationUserCredential
               (
                   initialToken: moderator.token,
                   refreshProactively: true,
                    tokenRefresher: cancellationToken => fetchNewTokenForCurrentUser(moderator.identity).GetAwaiter().GetResult(),
                    asyncTokenRefresher: cancellationToken => fetchNewTokenForCurrentUserasync(moderator.identity)
               );
```

the fetchNewTokenForCurrentUser method as below

```
   private async Task<string> fetchNewTokenForCurrentUser( string identity)
        {
              CommunicationIdentityClient communicationIdentityClient = new CommunicationIdentityClient(resourceConnectionString);
                CommunicationUser user = new CommunicationUser(identity);
                Azure.Response<CommunicationUserToken> tokenResponse = await communicationIdentityClient.IssueTokenAsync
                                                                                (
                                                                                    user,
                                                                                    scopes: new[] { CommunicationTokenScope.Chat }

                                                                                );
                string token = tokenResponse.Value.Token;
            
                return token;
        }
```

But this code is not working..
hope anyone will help me out.. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

We are looking at this issue you reported and will need further details. The generated tokens are supposed to last for 24 hours.

- Is this issue happening on your local box, or when the demo is deployed in azure as a web app ?
- When you mention 'it keep on expiring the treadID', which error are you seeing exactly?
- Do you have any error trace we can look at ?
- Could you capture a fiddler session (if the problem is reproducible locally?)

The first thing we can try is the following change on your code:

```
const string initialToken = "your-initial-token";
Uri apiUrl = new Uri("https://yourendpoint.dev.communication.azure.net");
const string identity = "your user id"; //i.e. 8:acs:1b5cc06b-f352-4571-b1e6-d9b259b7c776_00000006-6224-f48d-b274-5aaaaaaaaaaa";

var communicationUserCredential = new CommunicationUserCredential(
    initialToken: initialToken,
    refreshProactively: true,
    tokenRefresher: cancellationToken => fetchNewTokenForCurrentUser(identity).GetAwaiter().GetResult(),
    asyncTokenRefresher: cancellationToken => fetchNewTokenForCurrentUser(identity));

var chatClient = new ChatClient(apiUrl, communicationUserCredential);


//For the refresher logic. Note ValueTask vs Task
private async ValueTask<string> fetchNewTokenForCurrentUser(string identity)
{
    const string connectionString = "your connection string";
    CommunicationIdentityClient communicationIdentityClient = new CommunicationIdentityClient(connectionString);
    CommunicationUser user = new CommunicationUser(identity);
    Azure.Response<CommunicationUserToken> tokenResponse = await communicationIdentityClient.IssueTokenAsync
    (
        user,
        scopes: new[] { CommunicationTokenScope.Chat }

    );
    string token = tokenResponse.Value.Token;
    return token;
}
```

We will follow up with you once you have a chance to provide the above details.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to not only renew moderator token, but also renew thread members' tokens.

For example, you have a thread with A, B, C and moderator (this is created in C# code) in it. After 24 hours, tokens for all users are expired. If A still want to see the history messages, and send messages, then you need to renew A's token. Same logic applies for other users.

Hope it answer your question.

I saw a renew token pr is pending too: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/communication-services-web-chat-hero/pull/3